# Strange vertical overflow when viewport is greater than medium

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I'm using [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) to layout a some `div` elements in a vertical stack. But, I am having an issue when the viewport is above the `md` size the `div` elements overflow and produce a vertical scrollbar.

**Demo** https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/bingo-assets/index.html

Here's my `grid.scss` file:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/grid";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/responsive-utilities";

.row {
  @include make-row();
}

#content {
  @include container-fixed;
}

#promo-header {
  @include make-sm-column(12);
}

#subscribe {
  @include make-sm-column(12);
}

#video {
  @include make-sm-column(12);
}

#factoid {
  @include make-sm-column(12);
}
```

And below is the HTML:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="promo-header">
        <img width="100%" src="/images/promo.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="subscribe">
      <h2>Simply enter your details for a chance to win!</h2>
      <form name="subscribe">
        <div>
          <label>Firstname</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Surname</label>
          <input type="text" name="surname" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Telephone</label>
          <input type="text" name="telephone" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Postcode</label>
          <input type="text" name="postcode" />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Have you seen this product on TV?</label>
          <select name="question">
            <option value>Please Select</option>
            <option value="Y">Yes</option>
            <option value="N">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <button class="btn">Get Your Coupon</button>
        <small>Please note: Only one coupon available per person and only one email address allowed per person. Coupon valid 02.10.17 - 31.03.18. Redeemable by UK residents 18+ only in participating stores only.</small>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="video">
      <div id="video-container">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZZa7Kgo0apA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div id="description">
        <h2>Video Title</h2>
        <p>Do you want to cook amazing meals?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="factoid">
      <h2>Celebrity dietician Lucy Jones and Princes are working together to show families how they can eat well with canned fish.</h2>
      <p>Did you know our fillers are:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>High in protein</li>
        <li>Low in saturated fat</li>
        <li>A quick and easy lunch</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Learn More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I put a red border around each `div`. Here is what it looks like on a small or medium viewport:

[image: small viewport]

[image: > medium viewport]

Comment: Not much to see here, it would be a lot more helpful if we could troubleshoot the code and see what styles are applied, since this is where the problem will be identified. Can you produce a link to a live environment where the DOM can be inspected and explored?

Comment: There are no more styles applied. I removed them all except the grid styles while debugging. The only styles applied are the ones you see above. No live version. I'll see if I can get something online.

Comment: That would be ideal - to see the *rendered/processed* styles as you would when inspecting the elements in question.

Comment: I've uploaded a demo.

Comment: It appears the media query is being hit and making the width of the divs 100%. No idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace:

```
@include container-fixed;
```

with

```
@extend .container;
```

`container-fixed` appears to be a fluid container as can be seen from the `fluid-container` declaration:

```
.container-fluid {
  @include container-fixed;
}
```